# Error when inserting a value containing an apostrophe

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'am very new with `text` datatype in SQL Server 2008

I created table:

```
CREATE TABLE sample(id int identity,name varchar(20),Yell_Your_self text)
```

but I am facing problem with inserting

```
insert into sample values('ganesh','welcome to india')
insert into sample values('ganesh','welcome to india's largest temple')
```

First statement is working fine but how to execute second statement?

Comment: If you are getting an error, put the error message in your question

Comment: If this is specific to calling from C#, state that in your question, and include the C# code you are trying to execute.

Comment: In addition to all the other responses, please note that `text` [is deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) and you should not use it any more; use `(n)varchar(max)` instead.

Comment: @Pondlife - They are using `varchar(20)` according to the table definition (despite mentioning `text` in the question text)

Comment: @MartinSmith Good catch, I was looking at this side by side with the OP's [almost duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420914/passing-the-value-into-text-datatype-in-sql-server-2008) where he explicitly says "is datatype `text`", although obviously the descriptions are unreliable.

Comment: @Pondlife - Well trying to insert a 32 character string into a `varchar(20)` column would also explain why that one didn't work!

Comment: @MartinSmith Absolutely! The OP's curious reluctance to post any error messages isn't helping

Answer (score 3):

Try this one -

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.sample') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE dbo.[sample]

CREATE TABLE dbo.[sample]
(
      id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , name VARCHAR(20)
    , Yell_Your_self VARCHAR(2000)
)

INSERT INTO dbo.[sample] 
VALUES
    ('ganesh', 'welcome to india'), 
    ('ganesh', 'welcome to india''s largest temple')
```

**Update3:**

```
public int get(string val1,string val2) 
{ 
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        con.Open();

        int i = 0;

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.sample (name, Yell_Your_self) VALUES(@val1, @val2)", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", val1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", val2);
            i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        con.Close();
        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanking you very much jason

Comment: public int get(string val1,string val2)
        {
            string s="insert into sample values('"+val1+"','"+val2+"')";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s,con);
            con.Open();
            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            return i;
 
        }

Comment: try to add all params in an array by usin String.Replace("'","''"), then concat all value by comma to make it val1, val2,.... then pass it to to Sql.

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks for your comment. I fully agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

Likely throwing an error on the apostrophe in the india's

```
insert into sample values('ganesh','welcome to india''s largest temple')
```

Comment: this is working in sql server fine but i want to pass values from frient end like c#.net using ado.net

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have a single quote in the string, and a single quote is a string delimiter in SQL.

Try:

```
INSERT INTO  sample VALUES ('ganesh','welcome to india''s largest temple')
```

Comment: public int post(string val1,string val2)
        {
            string s="insert into sample values('"+val1+"','"+val2+"')";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s,con);
            con.Open();
            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            return i;
 
        }

Comment: (2) do NOT EVER pass variables in SQL statements from C# this way.  This exactly how SQL injection vulnerabilities are created, and it should never be done.  Instead, use the SqlParameter class to pass the SQL variables in.  It will prevent SQL injection vulnerabilities, and will also handle the necessary quote-escaping that is causing your issue (there are probably 20 other escaping things you need to do besides replacing the quotes).

Answer (score 0):

As you are already aware that the trouble SQL is facing is to escape an apostrophy in query, which is fixed i guess. To answer your second question about how to pass value from front end like C#, parametrized query is one of the good approach. As an alternative you can go with this one also which involves string manipulations to prepare a query:

```
public int get(string val1,string val2) 
{ 
    string temp = string.Concat(val1,"," + val2); // concatenate all your params
    temp = temp.replace("'","''").replace(",","','");  // replace any single qoute with escaped single quote
    string s="insert into sample values('" + temp +  "')"; // append altered string in query
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s,con); 
    con.Open(); 
    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    con.Close(); 
    return i; 
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

try this with passing dynamic value

```
insert into sample values(@name, N''' + @Yell_Your_self text + ''' )
```